# Is there any checklist for blog post before publishing it?

Tags: technique, tools, blog

The Context:
I often write through a blog platform. However, sometimes I feel that the content is too long and deep and sometimes I feel the content is written only on a surface-level about a topic. I mostly write on NGO's, volunteering experiences and daily experiences which I think should be written.

The Question:
I'm wondering, is there any tool or checklist that can help me to ensure that I've enough length of content to publish or any check-list to follow before publishing?

Answer (score 4):

I like this question!  There are a lot of marketing type posts if you google "blog checklist," but I found a few useful references.

Here's one that has a lot more on the keeping-your-content-focused portions of the checklist, which may help you if trying to figure out if your blog posts are "enough"
https://www.successfulblogging.com/blog-checklist/

> As bloggers, we risk confusing our readers if we delve into various vaguely related subjects all in one blog post. ...  There is nothing wrong with offering a plethora of tips or suggestions, but it needs to be tied together by one central theme.
>
> Some of the others ways that readers will find value are:
>   -   Case studies
>   -   Actionable content
>   -   Content that solves problems
>   -   Content that holds additional resources
>
> In multiple instances, I’ve found bloggers using out-of-date case studies and old resources. Circumstances change, some information becomes invalid, some information becomes more thorough. Bloggers need to check and re-check their sources before they publish.

This one seems to really think through a lot of the elements from brainstorming to editing the words: https://spinsucks.com/communication/ultimate-blog-checklist-guide/
Some of it is SEO focused, but it separates that process out from the content-creation element.

This one seems more SEO focused, but it has some strong content (just not as focused on the "writing" part of blogging):
https://writtent.com/blog/ultimate-blog-post-checklist-hit-publish-button/
the first 8 steps are about title/description/keywords, but it reminds you to check for "reputable" sources, and link to at least 2 (and it gives tips about judging "reputable" using Alexa), and also to link to a few of your OWN pages.  Then several focused on images (giving credit, editing them, including ALT tags! *yay accessability!*), and then a few more on white-space, H tags, bulleted lists.

It does seem a lot of the checklists I found are about everything *except* the writing!